# angularjs : on paste get pasted text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angularjs directive which listens to on paste event of my textarea:

```
element.on('paste', function (event) {
});
```

How do i **get the pasted text**? I tried:

```
event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
```

... and:

```
event.originalEvent.clipboardData
```

... but both didn't work. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple actually. You can just get the text with `element.val()` but you need to put it into setTimeout.

I did an example for you.

**Working JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vxcjw45d/

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <textarea paste-example></textarea>
        <div>{{ pastedText }}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.pastedText = '';
});

myApp.directive('pasteExample', function(){
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.on('paste', function() {

            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(element.val());
                scope.pastedText = element.val();
                scope.$apply();
            }, 5);

        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFn
    };
});
```